# blank space on the view when hiding uitabbar

Tags: ios, rotation, hide, tabbar

I know there are other posts about this issue, but they don't seem to work for me. When a particular view is pushed by my uinavigationcontroller in my app, I rotate the view to landscape mode and hide the tabbar. however, when the tabbar hides instead of displaying the view behind it displays a blank white space.

[image]

To solve this I used the following line of code in my viewDidLoad method as suggested by other posts about this issue, but it didn't solve it.

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
```

If anyone knows what's going on, please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set `setAutoresizingMask:` in your view (whether in nib or code) to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` or `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` (don't sure which one) that should do the trick. In case this donesn't solved your problem I guess that you hide the tabbar by using `setHidden:`. Try calling this instead.

```
VIEW_CONTROLLER_THAT_ABOUT_TO_SHOW.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES
[navigationController pushViewController: VIEW_CONTROLLER_THAT_ABOUT_TO_SHOW animated: YES];
```

Comment: oh man..was stuck in a big problem..it helped. thanks alott !!

Answer (score 0):

If your view is the right size then try calling [self.view setNeedsDisplay].  It should do something similar when you change the size though so I'm not sure.